# Make a fluttertext grow in a row until reaches max width, then overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have wanted to create the next behavior in flutter, but I can't figure out how.
Is having a text in a row with some other element, the text can have variable length. And the text space in the row should accommodate inside the row, unless the text space is larger than the remaining space in the row, then the text should use one of the text overflow options.
Here a diagram of the behavior, with the ellipsis type of text overflow:

[image: Diagram of the behavior]

I ave try using a combination of the row and expanded widgets, but I just can't make it.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried like this:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Flexible(
      child: Text("some long text", overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,),
    ),
    RaisedButton(
       child: Text("Button"),
    )
  ],
)
```

Comment: Yeah, it has the problem that does not go into ellipsis when the row exede the width, it throws the overflow exeption

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right. Try to wrap your Text into a Flexible. (I edited the code above)